# Application force closes when button is pressed

Tags: android, layout, button, android-intent, onclicklistener

I've just began on a new application and I added a button which in the past I've had no problem with but for some reason Its not working now. I'm just simply trying to teacher that button to another page. What do you think the problem is? (just ignore the spinners I haven't set those up yet)

TextingprojectActivity

```
public class TextingprojectActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button tut1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tutorial1);
        tut1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                startActivity(new Intent("practice.practice.TUTORIALONE "));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Tutorial1 Java

```
public class TutorialOne extends Activity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tutorial1);
    }

}
```

Main XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/place_arrays"
        android:prompt="@string/Place"/>
    <Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/tutorial1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/save"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

tutorial1 XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


</LinearLayout>
```

Android Manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="practice.practice"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".TextingprojectActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".TutorialOne"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="practice.practice.TUTORIALONE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Post the logcat, there should be a stack trace in there.

Comment: Try taking out the space at the end in `"practice.practice.TUTORIALONE "` when you create the new Intent.

Comment: just put   @Override on the onclick method

Comment: the intent... look at it....its uppercase! Its case sensitive and must match the package name and class!

Comment: @t0mm13b intent filter actions can be anything. The fact that the op chose to emulate the package name and class does make it confusing however.

Comment: @t0mm13b: Since the OP has `practice.practice.TUTORIALONE` declared as action in his `TutorialOne`'s intent filter, I'm guessing he's trying to use an implicit intent rather than an explicit one to launch that activity. // Edit: A--C beat me to it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your intent call like

```
Intent n = new Intent(TextingprojectActivity.this,TutorialOne.class);
        startActivity(n);
```

Also remove the `intent-filter` from the delaration of the rest activity from maniefst.

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="practice.practice.TUTORIALONE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Change it to like...

```
 <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".TextingprojectActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".TutorialOne"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your intent call to

```
Button tut1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tutorial1);
    tut1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent n = new Intent(TextingprojectActivity.this,TutorialOne.class);
            startActivity(n);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

if simply need to redirect to second activity Change your code as

```
Button tut1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tutorial1);
tut1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        startActivity(new Intent(TextingprojectActivity.this,TutorialOne.class););
    }
});
```

And Remove this Block From your manifest XML

```
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="practice.practice.TUTORIALONE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

What is this `practice.practice.TUTORIALONE???`